# PyTorch RuntimeError: Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

I'm using **PyTorch** for my **Logistic Regression** model but whenever I run the **model summary** I get an error

> RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)

**Code**

```
# Convert data to tensors
X_train = torch.Tensor(X_train)
y_train = torch.LongTensor(y_train)
X_test = torch.Tensor(X_test)
y_test = torch.LongTensor(y_test)

class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_features, num_classes):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x_in, apply_softmax = False):
        y_pred = self.fc1(x_in)
        if apply_softmax:
            y_pred = F.softmax(y_pred, dim = 1)
        return y_pred

INPUT_DIM = X_train.shape[1]
NUM_CLASSES = len(y_train.unique())

model = LogisticRegression(input_features = INPUT_DIM, num_classes = NUM_CLASSES)
print(model.named_parameters)
summary(model, input_size=(INPUT_DIM,))
```

My way does not work as expected, how do I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: Can you add `self.fc1= torch.nn.ModuleList(self.fc1)` in `__init__` and tell if it works out?

Comment: @AnirbanSaha I added but got an error ``TypeError: ModuleList.extend should be called with an iterable, but got Linear`` any idea why?

Comment: @ShadowWalker this input to ModuleList needs to be a list. So `self.fc1= torch.nn.ModuleList([self.fc1])` . However I don't think that this would solve your problem: nn.Linear already inherits nn.Module so putting it in a ModuleList wouldn't change the situation you're having. Can you try and use this code for inference instead of summary? Then I would be able to recreate your code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

> RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)

Ensuring the model and its weights were on the GPU helped:

```
model.to(device)
```

where device is defined:

```
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Using {device} device")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a notebook, then you most likely must have mixed up the variables. As `input_dim` is not defined in your snippet but might have been previously in your scope.

Assuming you are using `summary` from `torchsummary`, you don't need data to infer the model's structure, only the input shape. The following will work:

```
class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_features, num_classes):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_features, num_classes) # <- was input_dim
        
    def forward(self, x_in, apply_softmax = False):
        y_pred = self.fc1(x_in)
        if apply_softmax:
            y_pred = F.softmax(y_pred, dim = 1)
        return y_pred

INPUT_DIM = 10
NUM_CLASSES = 100

model = LogisticRegression(input_features=INPUT_DIM, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
summary(model, input_size=(INPUT_DIM,))
```

Comment: Kindly note there is no noticeable change from your code and mine.

Comment: There is, look on line 4: `input_dim` was replaced with `input_features`.

Comment: I applied the change you pointed out but that didn't solve the problem. The error still persists.

Comment: Which torch summary package are you using exactly?

Comment: ``from torchsummary import summary``

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed something from your code that you haven't put in your post? The code you provided works fine.